# Suppose I have a completely functioning program and I want to attach a test file how do I run it without adding h files to my program?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am a little bit new to cpp.  And all the concepts of 'includes' tho are important are pretty new and vague forme.   I have a few questions which are related to my main question .  The main question is:. I have a program which is  a file containing 'main' and other 5 classes let's call it 'PROG'.  I put them all in one file using no h files at all.  The program is running and all is good.   The point is, I now have 'test file ' which should test my program.  Test file is separated to h file and cpp file.  Is there any way to run everything without changing my program 'PROG'??  I don't want to create h files to my 'PROG' .  The problem is, the test file uses a few of the claseess written the program 'PROG'.  I thought about writing 'includes' cpp in the test file and putting 'pragma once'.  I don't know why it doesn't work.  Doesn't pragma once work for ' cpp includes'??

Or basically can anyone answer the general question.  Which is in short:. You have a file containing main and classes (which all in cpp file with no h file) . And you want to run it with another file (cpp+ h) but both files use each othrr. Which makes a circular use.   Is there a way to run it ?

Comment: In practice you should write your header file, so create and fill your own `myheader.h` file which you would `#include` from both `.cpp` files

Comment: `I don't want to create h files to my 'PROG'` That's where the problem is. In C++ include files are used to declare the *interface* to some part of your code. Since you have no header files your code has no interface and so can't be tested. You should rethink your requirements and use header files properly.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to write tests, however they will be run at an unspecified time either before or after your program runs, so won't be able to access `std::cout` etc. If your program uses any static objects, you won't be able to do this.

It will be much easier to move your `main` into a `main.cpp` that `#include`s definitions of your classes, and compile a separate `test_main.cpp` that instead runs your tests.

As a sketch of the former

```
class TestFailure{};

class RunAtStartup
{
    template<typename Func>
    RunAtStartup(Func f) { f(); }
}

extern double function_to_test(int arg);

static RunAtStartup run_function_to_test([]{
    // arrange
    int param = 0;

    // act
    double res = function_to_test(param);

    // assert
    if(res != 1.0) throw TestFailure();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

PROG:

```
class C {
  void f();
}

#ifndef TEST

void C::f() {
  // implementation
}

#endif // TEST
```

TEST:

```
#define TEST
#include "main.cpp"

// Your test code here can have instances to class C
C c;
c.f();
```

But take cpp/h approach as anyone recommends, which is everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I'd highly recommend using headers, but if you really don't want to modify your original file, you can `#include "main.cpp"` from your test file and redefine the main symbol during the inclusion. This allows you to create your own main method for the test program.

In test.cpp:

```
#define main real_main
#include "mymain.cpp"
#undef main

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::cout << "wah" << std::endl;
    int fakeargc = 1;
    const char* fakeargv[fakeargc] = { "hoo" };
    real_main(fakeargc, fakeargv);
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::cout << "hello world " << argv[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```